# Data Transformation and Loading with PHP

Tags: php, linux, cron

I'm looking for some options / opinions for the following scenario.

I've been approached to develop a solution which fetches 3 separate data feeds (web and ftp) every 1-5 minutes, recurring. Once the feeds are fetched, some transformation needs to occur before the feeds pushed to Magento.

I'm skilled in .NET so I'd normally either write this application in SQL Server Integration Services or a desktop app using Winforms and run on a scheduler.

I'm not skilled with PHP at all and I have very little Linux experience. I'm trying to put some recommendations in front of the guy who approached me to help him make the best decision as I don't think it makes sense to get separate hosting for my .NET app to push the data to an already existing Linux Server.

What methods do people use on Linux to perform tasks such as Data Transformation and Integration? The task will essentially download a file from the remote source, perform some validation and output an XML or CSV file. 
Should I be looking to run a CRON job every minute which calls a PHP page which does all the work? What happens with regards to timeouts and long running jobs?
What other approaches should be considered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write some kind of a daemon in plain php.
You can also write a script what does one iteration and launch it every N minutes using a cron.
It depends on what you like.
You can run php script with a command "php -f filename.php" from cron btw, you don't even need a web server for that.

Comment: That sounds like a good place to start; I didn't know I was able to run the PHP without a web server.
I'm still keen to hear other suggestions also.

Answer (score 0):

I think a cron job that runs every 5 minutes is a good solution. Using PHP from the command line, you can download the data using the [file_get_content](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function. If the input data is a CSV file, you can read it using [str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). If it's XML, you can use [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). From there, it should be fairly easy to manipulate the data.

Another option you could explore is using wget to download the files and then have a separate script that comes along and reads them.

Answer (score 0):

> What methods do people use on Linux to perform tasks such as Data
>   Transformation and Integration?

I usually use PHP. In general I think it is best to use whatever tool gets the job done well *and* you are comfortable with using. Since most of your experience is in .NET, you might want to see if you could do the bulk of the work in .NET.

> The task will essentially download a file from the remote source,
>   perform some validation and output an XML or CSV file.

In my opinion PHP is great for this sort of task. It's really easy to parse XML or CSV files with PHP--check out [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) for XML and [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv) for PHP files.

> Should I be looking to run a CRON job every minute which calls a PHP
>   page which does all the work? What happens with regards to timeouts and long running jobs?

I think going with a cron job is a fine way to go. As mephisto123 pointed out, you can [run PHP from the command line](http://php.net/cli), which is what you'll want to do. CLI scripts won't time out like pages will. They can run forever (provided you don't run out of memory or resources).

> What other approaches should be considered?

The cron job sounds loke a good approach. Another approach might be to have some kind of daemon that the server containing the data could notify each time the data updates.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. While I agree I should be coding it in .NET as it's what I know, I don't think it makes sense to get a server just for the purpose of hosting the .NET app while there is already a Linux server. I'll try and put something together in PHP otherwise I'll pass it off to someone else.